# Why can I create file runnig my vbs file using "Open with Command Prompt" but not without?

Tags: vbscript

I have a VB Script that creates a text file. When double-clicking the script to run it, I get an error on creating the file.

The code `objFileSystem.CreateTextFile(fileName)`

gives error: "*Object doesn't support this property or method*"

But when running the script by right-clicking and choosing "**Open with Command Prompt**", the script runs without errors. Why is this?

Comment: does the object "objFileSystem" exist?

Comment: Yeah, see the script is fine when running with command prompt.

Comment: Ok, so it amynot run fine, but the object exists yes. The file is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the script is working either ways.
but if you run it with cscript there will be not popup displaying an error.
it will be visible in the console which closes instantly.

Comment: OK, so it seems. I fooled myself since the file was created, I guess. Any idea on why the creation fails? (I.e. the file is created in file system, but VB says error)

Comment: please paste the complete code, maybe we can find the error. vbscript sometimes behaves strage and not as mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error when I tried to store the resulting text file object in a variable:

```
Set ObjFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
logFile = objFileSystem.CreateTextFile("test.txt")
```

gave "Object doesn't support this property or method."

But when I preceeded the second line with the keyword "set":

```
Set ObjFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set logFile = objFileSystem.CreateTextFile("test.txt")
```

Then it worked without error.

Answer (score 0):

So I found somewhat of an answer to this [here](http://www.vbscriptexperts.com/general/Q_25435597-Run-a-VB-script-by-Open-with-command-prompt.jsp)

When running "with Command Prompt", the `cscript.exe` interpreter is used (instead of `wscript.exe`). Why this interpreter is able to create files -- and not the other, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

How do you set objFileSystem?

Does your problem repeat with this sample code?

```
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFileSystem.CreateTextFile("test.txt")
```

Comment: Obviously in my environment I cannot repeat your problem. Maybe you could try to re-register scripting components, see bottom of this page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949140 You could always make test by trying to run same script on this machine as different user.